# Variables in URL

Tags: php, parameter-passing

Good morning,

I am building a  site for a client and I have come across a huge issue. I am allowing a public search where the user can select the search field from a dropdown and then input the search value in an input field. The SQL query runs and sends retunrs results. The unregistered user can then select to view the details for that particular user by clicking on view. Now obviously clicking on the view (link) they are redirected to another page using php.

```
> <td><a href='http://localhost/mygiftsite/pub_list_view.php?user=<?php echo $user_id;?>'>View</a></td>
```

This produces the following URL: `http://localhost/mygiftsite/pub_list_view.php?user=1`. This page then displays all the lists that are made public by that particular registered member. The unregistered user can then view those lists by clicking on any of the fields and that redirects to `http://localhost/mygiftsite/pub_item_view.php?list=9`.

My problem is that a user can just change the value of the list variable/index in the url to view lists for other users and lists with a privacy setting of private which should not be allowed. Just to clarify, the list has a privacy field not the user. The registered user decides to either keep a list private or to make a list public. Public lists should be accessible via a member search and private list should not be able to display. I stopped users from accessing pages without being logged in using the following code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
        header("location: http://localhost/mygiftsite/login.php");
    }
?>
```

But I want to allow unregistered users to search and view public lists. Please can you help me resolve this issue.

1. Is it possible to "hide" the variable so the value cannot be changed?
2. How do I stop users from simply changing the value of the list variable by simply clicking in the URL
3. If they change the value by simply changing the URL how do I protect my user's list should the privacy be set to private?
4. I do not want to go the .htaccess method as you can still simply change the parameter value.

My main concern is that a parameter can simply be changed in the address bar. How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to build an entire website here... Not trying to be offensive but this question is way too broad for this site.

Comment: Does your registered users already have a privacy setting? Couldn't really understand that sentence. 
Just like redirecting non logged in users, you can do the same if the profile they're trying to view has its privacy setting set to private.

Comment: I am not asking you to build an entire site. Did you even read the request? I need to block a list which has been set to private from being accessed by simply changing the parameter value. I am not asking you to code anything. I am asking to be directed in the correct direction with a simple use .htaccess or tell me to use this block of code. I am sorry but I am uncertain how this is apparently too broad...

Comment: Each list has a privacy field which can be set to either private or public. Public lists should be accessible and private lists should not however this does not address my issue. My issue is that anyone can simply change the value of the parameter to open lists they did not search. How do I stop that????

Answer (score 0):

You need to check in every private page that the user loading it is the logged user.
Example:

```
//keep logged user. Store in session during sign-in
$loggedUserId = $_SESSION['loggedUserId'];

//from URL GET parameter
$otherUserId = $_GET['userid'];
$listId = $_GET['list'];

if($loggedUserId==$otherUserId)
      //do something, allow access
else {
      //retrieve the list record based on $listId, get $isPrivate field

      //do something else, don't allow access
      if($isPrivate == true )
           header("location: http://localhost/mygiftsite/login.php");
}
```

Comment: Aris, thank you for your answer to my question. This is what I used for the pages that only registered user should be able to access but I need to do something similar for public pages. I am allowing my registered users to create public lists I want public data to be accessible but lists marked as private not to be accessible.

Comment: how do you know that a list is private or public?

Comment: When a user creates a new list they have a dropdown to select the option public or private. this is stored in the table list as field privacy and can only be private/public

Comment: you need to retrieve the list record and based on the private field expand your login. see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like it will work. I am rebuilding my pub_search.php page. Will let you know the result. Thank you in advance for taking the time to assist.